# How do I check if my table exists in Firebase?

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I check if my table has any values? I mean I want to do if (table has any values) {///}

Comment: Neither of the databases provided by Firebase (Realtime Database and Firestore) have something called a "table".  Typically "table" is used to talk about the structure of SQL databases.  Realtime Database has nodes and Firestore has collections of documents.  Can you reword your question to include exactly which product you're working with, and what you are trying to query?

Comment: Im using firebase's realtime database. I meant nodes instead of tables. Im sorry im new. I want to see if (a node (I think) is created)

Answer (score 1):

There is no query to check if a node exists without also fetching all the data under it.  You will have to fetch the node and check to see if the snapshot at that node is not empty.

Comment: How do i feych the node and check if the snapshot at that node is not empty?